# In RISCV Exception/Interrupt Handlers, how to return to the correct privilege mode?

Tags: exception, interrupt, privileges, riscv

Suppose I have configured all exceptions and interrupts to be handled in machine-mode...

How do my machine-mode handlers know to put `PRV_U` or `PRV_M`, etc. into `mstatus.MPP` before executing `mret` so execution may continue in the privilege mode the trap was taken *from*?

Another way to ask the same question is how do the CSRs look different upon arrival in my machine-mode handlers when arriving *from* User/Supervisor/Hypervisor/Machine mode...?

For example...

```
uintptr_t
exception_handler(uint64_t cause)
{
  const uint64_t hartid = read_csr(mhartid);

  switch (cause) {
    // Do stuff to "claim", "handle", and "clear" each exception "cause"...
    // Maybe it's an ecall?  Maybe a page-fault?  Doesn't matter...
  }

  clear_csr(mstatus, MSTATUS_MPP);
  set_csr(mstatus, (trek_uint64_t)(???? << 11));  // <-- what goes here!?!!

  return read_csr(mepc) + 4;  // There is an `mret` just after this return.
}
```

Comment: You're told what privilege was interrupted.

Comment: @ErikEidt, Where? How? In my ISR, mstatus will contain PRV_M, because that is the privilege level it is running.

Comment: You don't really need to set MPP bits when returning from exception handler. These bits are already set when exception was taken. As per the riscv privilidge spec __When a trap is taken from privilege mode y into privilege mode x, xPIE is set to the value of xIE; xIE is set to 0; and xPP is set to y__. So don't clear and set the MPP bits in your exception_handler. Those are already set properly.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/rivosinc/JumpStart/blob/833349e6c9c642fcaa65d8e572c4395497c49fc6/src/common/start.machine.S#L259C18-L259C18. This can provide you some idea about trap handler.

Comment: Also as per my understanding, you don't always increment `mepc`. At least not in the case of interrupts. `mepc` points to the instruction that was interrupted. So we still need to run that instruction.

On the other hand in case of some exceptions, we do need to increment it. For example In case of trap due to WFI, or ecall. In short we increment mepc for any instruction that is serviced or emulated by the exception handler. By serviced I mean instruction like ecall.